# Java search form to query IP numbers

Tags: java, string, ms-access, input, inetaddress

```
String Ipnumbers = request.getParameter("Ipnumbers");
String variant = request.getParameter("variant");
String strQuery = "SELECT Ipnumbers, username FROM brane where val(Ipnumbers) ";
if (Ipnumbers.equal("superior"))
  strQuery += "> " + Ipnumbers ;
```

I have in my MS Access database a list of IP numbers (192.03.34.44) declared as text. How can I use a user search form (user input field named Ipnumbers) to query my database? The question is- what is the declaration format or how to convert from string to whatever these dotted numbers are- to be recognised by Java. Cheers. Example: I did the same for integer value I have in my database like:

```
  int nStudentnumbers = Integer.parseInt(Studentnumbers);
```

how can use or parse the dotted IP numbers as? They are not integer neither double?
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You should have to use `PreparedStatement`,

```
String strQuery = "SELECT Ipnumbers, username FROM brane where Ipnumbers=?";
PreparedStatement statement=connection.prepareStatement(strQuery);
statement.setString(1,Ipnumbers);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am having problem with parsing the dotted IP numbers in my queries. I have updated my question :)

Comment: @Brane - Take a look at post -  [Sort IP addresses in an Access database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sort-ip-addresses-in-an-access-database-HP001164613.aspx) - They've split Ip string into four parts.

Comment: thanks buddy, I just read your post but it doesn't answer my question :( , my problem is actually how to parse Ipnumbers in my query, like can i declare it as     int nIpnumbers = Integer.parseInt(Ipnumbers); ?

Comment: I know that (you can use replace(ip,'.','') MSAccess func to remove dot) but there isn't *straight* way to parse IP string into *int* at database level.

Comment: Something like - `SELECT val(replace(Ipnumbers,'.','')) as Ipnumbers,username from tableName where val(replace(Ipnumbers,'.',''))>=?` - (have not tested)

Comment: thanks, I have just tested your code, it does not work , I get the following error,     `java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in number in query expression 'val(replace(Ipnumbers,'.','')) > 192.145.66.23'.`